# Adding SVG White Space

Tags: graphics, svg, white-space, adjustbox

The questions I have seen similar to this have been about removing white space from SVGs, but I would like to keep mine.
I have a 3x3 grid of SVGs. Each has the same viewBox dimensions. However, `includeSvg` zooms in to include minimal white space. The issue is that I would like each of the figures to be of the same scale, so how can I enforce the dimensions/have LaTeX zoom out?

````
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\makebox[0pt][r]{}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{1.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{2.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{3.svg}\\
\makebox[0pt][r]{}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{4.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{5.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{6.svg}\\
\makebox[0pt][r]{}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{7.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{8.svg}
\includesvg[width=0.25\textwidth]{9.svg}
\end{figure}```
````

Comment: See the doc for [package `svg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg) and search for `inkscapearea`

Comment: Your svg files could contain anything, including nothing. So what's left for us do do is ... using magic and telepathy ... // However, try working thorugh theses steps and see, whether you can post something more sepcific and boiled-down. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! While we were able guess you problem (and point you to a duplicate question) here, this is not usually possible without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973), so be sure to include one with your next question. Happy texing!